# Sitecore Commerce 9 Installation Error - Unable to Stop SQL Service

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework, installation, powershell

I am getting the error not able to start SQL Server Service.

**Error:**

> Restarting SQL Server
>
> Something went wrong restarting SQL server again
>
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration: Service 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
>   (MSSQLSERVER)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot
>   stop SQLPBENGINE service on computer '.'. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253
>   char:21
>   +                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

**Script:**

```
#Requires -Version 3
param(
    [string]$SiteName = "C360.local",   
    [string]$SiteHostHeaderName = "C360.local", 
    [string]$SqlDbPrefix = $SiteName,
    [string]$CommerceSearchProvider = "SOLR"
)

$global:DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$modulesPath=( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "Modules" )
if ($env:PSModulePath -notlike "*$modulesPath*")
{
    $p = $env:PSModulePath + ";" + $modulesPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)
}


$params = @{
        Path = Resolve-Path '.\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json' 
        SiteName = $SiteName
        SiteHostHeaderName = $SiteHostHeaderName 
        InstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$SiteName"
        XConnectInstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$($SiteName)_xconnect"
        CertificateName = $SiteName
        CommerceServicesDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)    #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        CommerceServicesDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments"
        CommerceServicesGlobalDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_Global"       
        SitecoreDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)            #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        SitecoreCoreDbName = "C360_Core"
        SitecoreUsername = "sitecore\admin"
        SitecoreUserPassword = "b"
        CommerceSearchProvider = $CommerceSearchProvider
        SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr"
        SolrRoot = "C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrService = "solr662"
        SolrSchemas = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SolrSchemas" )
        SearchIndexPrefix = ""
        AzureSearchServiceName = ""
        AzureSearchAdminKey = ""
        AzureSearchQueryKey = ""
        CommerceEngineDacPac = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.*\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"       
        CommerceOpsServicesPort = "5015"
        CommerceShopsServicesPort = "5005"
        CommerceAuthoringServicesPort = "5000"
        CommerceMinionsServicesPort = "5010"        
        SitecoreCommerceEngineZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.2.2.126.zip"        
        SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.2.19"        
        SitecoreIdentityServerZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.IdentityServer.1.*.zip"
        CommerceEngineCertificatePath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\storefront.engine.cer"       
        SiteUtilitiesSrc = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SiteUtilityPages" )  
        HabitatImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-*.zip"    
        AdvImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Adventure Works Images.zip"    
        CommerceConnectModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Connect*.zip"  
        CommercexProfilesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce ExperienceProfile Core *.zip"    
        CommercexAnalyticsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core *.zip" 
        CommerceMAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation Core *.zip"    
        CommerceMAForAutomationEngineModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation for AutomationEngine *.zip" 
        CEConnectPackageFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect*.update"
        PowerShellExtensionsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Sitecore PowerShell Extensions*.zip"
        SXAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Sitecore Experience Accelerator*.zip"
        SXACommerceModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontThemeModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Themes*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Habitat Catalog*.zip"
        MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        UserAccount = @{
            Domain = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            UserName = 'CSFndRuntimeUser'
            Password = 'Pu8azaCr'
        }
        BraintreeAccount = @{
            MerchantId = ''
            PublicKey = ''
            PrivateKey = ''
        }
        SitecoreIdentityServerName = "SitecoreIdentityServer"       
    }

if ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "SOLR") {
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params   
}
elseif ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "AZURE"){
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip InstallSolrCores
}
```

Comment: can you add your installation scripts to the question

Comment: Are you running powershell console with elevated privileges - as administration

Comment: @VladIobagiu I had added the installation script.

Comment: @SumithPD: I am already running as Administrator. Seems the Powershell is not able to cess the SQL service.

Comment: Do you have Named instance on SQL Server? How do you access SQL Server through SSMS? Can you paste screenshot?

Comment: @PeterProchazka: SQL instance can be connected through the Computer Name.

Comment: @SaiRajR - Please accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for supporting me. The issue was from the SQL instance. We need to enable the TCP Ip protocol for the SQL server and make sure "SQL Server PolyBase Engine (MSSQLSERVER) " is in the running status. If service is in starting status we need to start it again.

[image: SQL Poly base engine Services]